# display result in UI

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I am building a user interface with pyside and Qt. I have done nice calculations that I want to display the results of in the UI. 
The results are 1 float each and they are stored in:

```
self.dist_total_disp
self.time_total_disp
```

I have tried displaying them with a label like:

```
    self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.plot_window =QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

    self.dist_time_label = QtGui.QLabel()
    self.dist_time_label.setText("total distance = self.dist_total_disp \ntotal survey time = self.time_total_disp ")
    self.plot_window.addWidget(self.dist_time_label)

   ----COMPILE UI----

    self.setLayout(self.layout)
    self.layout.addLayout(self.plot_window)
```

But the problem here is that the setText requires a string and self.dist_total_disp and self.time_total_disp cannot be called from within the string.

Also I would like to display the result on the lower right side of the VBox but I don't want to change QVBoxLayout() to QHBoxLayout().

I feel there should be a QtGui tool that is more suitable for this but I could't find one in the documentation.

### Edit:

Note that the calculations are done with input from the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
self.dist_time_label.setText("total distance = {0} \ntotal survey time = {1} ".format(self.dist_total_disp, self.time_total_disp))
```

For adding the label at the lower side of the `VBox` you should add a spacer above it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the string with the values you want to display

```
self.dist_time_label.setText("total distance = %f\ntotal survey time = %f" % (self.dist_total_disp, self.time_total_disp))
```

For displaying the label on the lower right side you would use the `alignment` paramter of [`addWidget(widget, stretch=0, alignment=0)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#addWidget)

```
self.plot_window.addWidget(self.dist_time_label, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
```